# Customize user interface for n8n workflows

Tags: automation

Is it possible to customize the user interface for n8n workflows? if possible, can someone give an idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source code for all the frontend code inside their repository: https://github.com/n8n-io/n8n/tree/master/packages/editor-ui

The editor-ui folder inside packages is what you are looking for.

The app is written using Vue.js ans it's very easy to understand. You can see the `n8n-theme*.scss` files in the mentioned folder that could be a good starting point.

Feel free to add / share ideas on what you're looking to do and I'll try to help if possible.

Also they have a very active community that can be found here: https://community.n8n.io/